# On Android in Cucumber/Calabash, how do I test with a webview iframe?

Tags: android, iframe, calabash

I can locate an iframe in an Android webview, but I need to interact with it. Various pages suggest

```
query("webView css:'iframe'", :stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString => '...')
```

but that results in "No such method found: stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString([String])" and it looks like an iOS function, so I'm pretty sure this is an iOS-only solution: I need Android.

I know I can pass javascript queries in by opening them in a URL, but I've only experienced getting stuff out of an Android webview with specially-code Chrome objects linked in to the application.

Any ideas for getting data out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS responses are correct, you should use javascript to get the contents of an iframe. However, you should use `evaluate_javascript(query_string, javascript)` to evaluate javascript in Android. e.g

`evaluate_javascript("webview", "return document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById('...').getBoundingClientRect();")`

Use the coordinates to tap the view.

If the rect is not parsed correctly, you could do something like this:

    `var boundingBox = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById('main').getBoundingClientRect();
    var rect = {};
    rect.width = boundingBox.width;
    rect.height = boundingBox.height;
    rect.left = boundingBox.left;
    rect.top = boundingBox.top;
    return rect;`

Secondly, `query('webView css:#grabby')` is not a valid query. `query('webView css:"#grabby"')` or `query("webView css:'#grabby'")` is. You are most likely running a (very) old version of Calabash-Android if the test-server is crashing instead of reporting it.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks - particularly copying the bbox to a new hash: without it, it was just returning "{}".

Comment: I found that the Javascript coordinates needed to be offset by the containing iframe's location within the webView, and then both offset and scaled to the Android coordinate system before they can be used to click on things. In particular, I determined the webView's Android and Javascript scaling factor by dividing query('webview index:0')'s width and height by Javascript's window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight. I need to test this on additional phones, but it looks plausible so far.

Comment: You are probably right. You can take a look at how we scale and transform webview coordinates here https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/test-server/instrumentation-backend/src/sh/calaba/instrumentationbackend/query/WebContainer.java#L192

Comment: Tested successfully on a few phones. Scaling works best if you don't forget that integers can't express 1.5 very well. I do wish Ruby had SOME support for static typing.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote what amounted to an answer while I was exploring, but I'm posting it here to save someone else time (hopefully).

---

I can successfully run Javascript in the view:

```
query("webView index:0", :loadUrl => 'javascript:alert("Hello")')
```

so I can probably arrange to press buttons plausibly enough for testing:

```
query("webview index:0", :loadUrl => 'javascript: ifr = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]; idoc = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document; idoc.getElementById('myCheck').click(); false')
```

To get data out again, I can create a DIV and set its title (for example) with some 'return' value:

```
query("webView index:0",  :loadUrl => 'javascript:var idiv = document.createElement("div"); idiv.id="grabby"; document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(idiv); idiv.title="some return value"; false')
```

(The trailing 'false' in the javascript: command is there to prevent the result of running the javascript: command from replacing the page - that took a while to work out.)

I can look into the iframe too:

```
query("webView index:0",  :loadUrl => 'javascript:var idiv = document.getElementById("grabby"); ifr = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]; idoc = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document; idiv.title = idoc.getElementsByTagName("input")[3].id; false')
```

When I tried to retrieve it with

```
query('webView css:#grabby')
```

it hung for a while, then crashed with a timeout:

```
HTTPClient::ReceiveTimeoutError: execution expired
    from /Users/tim./.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:876:in `gets'
    from /Users/tim./.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:876:in `block in parse_header'
    from ...
```

curiously, query('webView css:"*"') mostly seems to work without timeouts, and reports the 'grabby' DIV complete with the title string

```
query('webView css:"*"').find { |e| e['id'] == 'grabby' }
```

so that's useful enough. I'll have to write some horrible recursive descent thingy to fish out the iframe's contents - perhaps make the div invisible and just copy the htmlContent there.

I'm really not sure why the direct query crashes.

Comment: You probably don't need to create the div or load the url.  I've done some complex work on a app that used iframes using the JavaScript iOS WebView API.  _No such method found: stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString([String])_ It is iOS only and you should know the API has changed for WKWebView.  https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/06-WebView-Support